# ImportError while doing Custom Object Detection with Tensorflow version 1.14.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I am trying to detect an object with Tensorflow as described [here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10).

After runnig this command in the training part

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'center_net_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (E:\Projects\Tensorflow_10Nov20\models-master\research\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)
```

Here is the relevant code

```
from object_detection.protos import center_net_pb2 as object__detection_dot_protos_dot_center__net__pb2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

don't know what your protoc version is but try to upgrade it to atleast version 3.7.x, this might solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Okay i'll try @Digital_entity